# JAVA How does the inheritance work under the hood?

Tags: inheritance, jvm

How does the inheritance work under the hood in Java? What does JVM do in order to accompish the inheritance? When the object is created and stored on the heap is it containing the superclass' code? Is that the whole magic?

Comment: The Java Language Specification only specifies what the result of running a Java program is, it does not specify how to achieve this result. In particular, the Java Language Specification doesn't even specify that there has to be a JVM *at all*, and even if there is a JVM, it doesn't specify how that JVM is implemented. The JVM is free to copy the superclass code into the subclass, or it is free to link to it, or it can do something else entirely. The JVM doesn't even need to have a heap.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag Well I've read in a site called "javapoint" or something like that that when you create an object of subclass an object of the superclass is also created. So there are 2 objects on the heap and I assume that the sublcass object is accessing the superclass' content via a reference. Maybe this is why there is the "super" keyword? What do you think?

Comment: The Java Language Specification only specifies what the result of running a Java program is, it does not specify how to achieve this result. Any implementation of the Java programming language is free to do whatever it wants, as long as the program has the result that is specified by the Java Language Specification. It is perfectly valid to implement it the way you describe, although it would be a very stupid way to implement it that way and I don't know of any Java implementation that does it. However, I don't know every Java implementation in the world, and even for those I *do* know about,

Comment: I don't know every little detail there is to know about them. So, the fact that I don't know any Java implementation that does what you describe does not mean that an implementation like that doesn't exist. And the fact that I believe that would be a stupid way to implement, does not mean that somebody isn't doing it anyway, or that there are certain restrictions in their environmental context that force them to do it that way or that even make it a good idea.

Comment: Why do you need to know? Do you want to modify a specific JVM? Do you need to know the performance characteristics of subclassing? ... provide more background for your question.